# Дополненная реальность Android

Tags: android

Кто знает, какие классы могут использоваться в Дополненной реальности в Android ? Есть видео, с камеры на которое нужно наложить например текст или альфа изображение поверх кадров в видео. Как это можно достигнуть, достаточно ли тут обойтись Android SDK ? Важно накладывать на каждый кадр потокового видео

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [OpenCV](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV)

Имеются отличные примеры [в Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jnardari.opencv_androidsamples&hl=ru) с открытым исходным кодом [на GitHub](https://github.com/joaopedronardari/OpenCV-AndroidSamples).

Также имеется множество статей на хабре: [раз](https://habrahabr.ru/post/262089/), [два](https://habrahabr.ru/post/254737/), [три](https://habrahabr.ru/post/217377/) и [отличная документация](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html).

Ну а по теме ruSO - вопрос слишком общий.